# QML Canvas with Abstract Item Model

Tags: qt, canvas, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I have a abstract item model with layers of data( similar to map layers )

I wish to draw them using canvas(polyline, text etc ), Is it possible to use any qml views and draw the layers on top of each other?

Please recommend if there is any better way of solving the problem.

Comment: [Canvas](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-canvas.html)

Comment: + [`Repeater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) - Provide a **MVCE** for further help.